# Run Github action when pull request origin branch has certain prefix

Tags: github, github-actions, slack

I am trying to create actions which behave differently depending on the prefix of the origin (head?) branch.

Current use case is sending a Slack message when a branch named `bug/<anything>` is getting merged into `main`.

I've tried setting a script up like the following.

**report-bugfix.yml**

```yaml
name: Report Bugfix
on:
  push: 
    branches: 
      - main
jobs:
  run_if:
    if: startsWith(github.ref_name, 'bug/')
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: 8BitJonny/gh-get-current-pr@2.1.0
        id: PR
      - name: Slack Notify
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.2.0
        env:
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_CHANGELOG }}
          SLACK_USERNAME: BugBuster Bot
          SLACK_COLOR: ${{ job.status }}
          SLACK_TITLE: 'A new bug has been fixed! :beetle:'
          SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_body }}
```

My action currently gets skipped as the if statement returns false, so I assume my syntax or variable checking is wrong.

Any action sharks who are aware of a elegant solution to my use case?

Edit: Changed following line `if: startsWith(github.ref_name, 'bug/**')` with `if: startsWith(github.ref_name, 'bug/')`

However testing with the branchname `bug/action-testing` the issue still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was related to looking for the `push` event. The event doesn't seem to know about where a push came from, so it was essentially impossible to locate that information for me.

Instead I can use the `pull_request` event, which sets the `github.head_ref` variable to the branch which I am creating the request from.

To ensure the action only triggered when the pull request was closed and merged, I used the type `closed` and `github.event.pull_request.merged == true` in an if statement.

My final script is as follows:

```
name: Bug Changelog
on:
  pull_request:
    types: 
      - closed
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true && startsWith(github.head_ref, 'bug/')
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: 8BitJonny/gh-get-current-pr@2.1.0
        id: PR
      - name: Slack Notify
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.2.0
        env:
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_CHANGELOG }}
          SLACK_USERNAME: BugBuster Bot
          SLACK_COLOR: ${{ job.status }}
          SLACK_TITLE: 'A new bug has been fixed! :beetle:'
          SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{ steps.PR.outputs.pr_body }}
          SLACK_FOOTER: ''
          MSG_MINIMAL: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The double asterisk after the `bug/` is unnecessary. Unless you only want names like `bug/**abcd` to pass, the `**` will get treated as characters. With the `startsWith` function, you only need to pass the actual characters to match, and don't need to worry about wildcards.

More info on Github actions expressions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions

Comment: I attempted this variation, but with the same issue persisting (I also edited my question to use the correct syntax).